# Is it possible to change the location where System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control downloads XAP files?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, silverlight, webbrowser-control

I open IE as a WebBrowser control and navigate to a Silverlight site (do not ask me why, please).

Is it possible to change programmatically the location where the WebBrowser control downloads the XAP files?

Comment: From the webbrowser control document, I didn't find the related method, might be you could try to use the [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file) class to create a xap file, please refer to [this article]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file)

Comment: I am sorry, why do I need to create a xap file?